# именование пакетов в java

Tags: java, package

в моем проекте есть классы с бизнес-логикой и классы-сущности (объект pojo),как правильно назвать пакет для классов сущностей?
(например, класс гонщик, у которого есть поля имя и время гонки)

Comment: Ин рашн плиз:-)

Comment: в общем, как правильно именовать пакет для классов сущностей в java, то есть для классов без какой-то логики, которые имеют просто набор полей типа имя и тд)

Comment: Как тут дать объективный ответ? Нужно больше вводных. Какая ответственность этого класса сущности? Используете анемичную (https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) модель? С какими другими классами взаимодействует? Названия пакетов диктуется логикой разбиения классов, а это в свою очередь их ответственностями и взаимодействиями.

Comment: Если вы собираетесь публиковать свой проект, то надо обеспечить уникальность полных имен классов. Обычно это достигается употреблением реверсированного имени своего домена в начале имени всех пакетов (т.е. если ваш домен `example.com`, то имена пакетов начинаются с `com.example`). В остальном на ваше усмотрение, ну желательно, чтобы имена пакетов отражали смысл того, что в них находится, и желательно соблюдать конвенции -- только нижний регистр в именах пакетов. Если это чисто учебный проект, для себя, то вообще можете называть как хотите.